# The name for "anonymous " graph

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a name for this type of graphs: given a labeled graph, it's impossible to restore labels for unlabeled graph or even increase a probability of having any  label

```
a ) o-----o   b)   o--o  o----o c)  o--o d) o---o
                   | /   |    |     | /     | /
    o-----o        o     o----o     o       o---o
```

for example graphs (a) and (c) are considered to be anonymous, in the graph (d) you can identify hanging label, in the graph (b) you can increase probabilities from 1/7 to 1/3 for the first cluster and 1/4 to the second.

I am right that: "anonymous" graph, should be empty, full, or consist from the full clusters of the same size?

Comment: Your condition amounts to saying that all vertices must have the same degree and all faces the same number of edges, I guess. This will hold for a square or an hexagon with three diameters, and many others, I guess.

Comment: Vertex-transitive? Symmetric?

Comment: @IvanNeretin thank you, that it is. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vertex-TransitiveGraph.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@IvanNeretin posted an answer in the comment section, that is the Vertex-Transitive Graph
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vertex-TransitiveGraph.html

Answer (score 0):

About the name part, I think you have the answer already.

About your assumption on the properties:
A cycle of length 4 already violates your assumption if I understand your intent of anonymous graphs properly. (E.g. you can't identify vertices by graph properties like neighbors.)